# Do I need to test boundary classes in unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, jax-rs

I've written JAX-RS restapi, I have some boundary classes like: PersonResource, StudentResource , etc. When I receive the http requests from these classes, I  delegate these request to logic classes. So do I need to test these boundary classes?

```
@POST
@Path("/register")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response register(UserRequest req) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(StringUtils.isNoneBlank((networkName)));
    User user = repository.add(req);
    return Response.ok().entity(user).build();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no ... depends.

If you are using this classes in logic then yes.
If they are just data value classes then more or less no.

But rather than this I would test the REST API itself (integration test).

For instance you can use: [RestFuse](http://developer.eclipsesource.com/restfuse/)

You can test edge cases and make sure the data sent to your methods is always valid, and you create an appropriate response in case it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, yes.  However, you might be asking this question because you're not familiar with how to test them.

For example, why do you test the internals of your code instead of the actual functionality that you're delivering?